# How to get vs code's еrror lens in neovim?

Tags: plugins, neovim

Does anyone know about some kind of neovim plugin/feature, that recreates behaviour from vscode's error lens extension? It is just showing errors on the side of the code. Here's an example:
[image: The screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the exact plugin I was looking for: https://github.com/folke/trouble.nvim :D